# Updating a Document in Java

Tags: java, mongodb

I've got a little question on using MongoDB in Java and how to update a Document

I want to update my Documents which should represent a User Account for his Money . The POJO contains an id, a Value for his cash, and a List of his bank accounts.

A Bank Account is containing an id for the BankAccount, a Value for the Money the Accounts is containing and a List of his Transactions.

In this Transactions List, one Object represent the Transactions from one other BankAccount so one Object there Contains an ID  and a List with the single payments, no Datum no extra Stuff, just this. And now I want to update this Document.

Updating the cash is no Problem but updating the Bank Accounts sees some tricky for me(For most of you not  I thought).

In my Program the BankAccounts is representing by an Object looking like this:

```
public class BankAccount{
 private int id;
 private long money;
 private HashMap<Integer,ArrayList<Long>> transactions;

 public BankAccount(int id, long money ){
    this.id = id;
    this.money = money;
    transactions = new HashMap<>();
 }

 public Document getAsDocument(){
    Document object = new Document();
    object.append("money",money);
    object.append("bankID",id);
    this.transactions.forEach((aKey,aValue)->{
        Document otherDocument = new Document();
        otherDocument.append("bankID",aKey);
        otherDocument.append("transactions",aValue.toArray());
        object.append(aKey,otherDocument);
    });
    return new Document("§push",object);
}
```

}

Will it work when is just call the Method "getAsDocument" for every BankAccount and add this to an Document where also the cash is in or will there be a better way or will this doesent work either ?m

-Hannes

Comment: All the `otherDocument` created in the loop are not used anywhere.

Comment: What is `§push`? I assume you mean `$push` and you use this to run an `update`. How does the whole update look like (you need an array field to push into)?

Comment: Yeah, i meant $push I've just written the Method shortly to show what i mean What do you mean with "otherDocument created in the loop are not used anywhere" ? can I just update one entry every time?

Comment: Or what would you prefer to update such a Document @Thilo ?

Comment: Re:  "otherDocument created in the loop are not used anywhere" : You have a local variable `otherDocument` in that loop and build a `Document` instance there. But this is not used anywhere, so that the loop has no effect at all.

Comment: Oh that's what you meant, yeah I have written this method shortly to show what I mean it does not belongs to my project right now.  I will edit my Post Thank you